# Run a C# Application periodically to update database

Tags: c#, sql, database, triggers

I would like to know whether it is possible to run a C# console or ASP.NET application periodically.

My purpose is to **automatically** do the following steps once a **month**:

1) **Query** a **Source** database.

2) **Take** the result of the query at (1) and **manipulate** them by using **LINQ** and **C#**, for instance by checking if a certain value is already present in the Destination database.

3) **Store** the derived data in a Destination database.

The application has to run on a **Windows Server 2008**, the **Source** database is in a **SQL 2005 Server** and the **Destination** database is in a **SQL 2008 Server**.

I tried to create for instance a **SSIS** package but it won't do the job since I cannot add any logic.

Anybody has any suggestion?

Comment: This can be done in SSIS. You have the script task to write your script.

Comment: Why do you need to use C#? Could you just encapsulate this logic in one or more stored procedures and schedule them with SQL Agent?

Comment: Alternatively you can also create a command line dotnet application and schedule it via Scheduled Task or SQL Server agent.

Comment: You CAN add logic to SSIS.  This is the kind of thing SSIS was made for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should create a Scheduled Task to perform this. Look here: Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Task scheduler

And as you stated, yes - a console app is highly recommended.

---

Edit

I agree with @andynormancx in that SSIS may be a better way to do this; however, it is commonly accepted to create a console app executed by a scheduled task. This is where it comes down to your resources, time, and expertise: it may or may not be worth the effort to learn enough about SSIS to create a package in SqlServer to do what you need. If someone were to give a complete answer using SSIS to perform this task, I would certainly bow to that expertise.

Comment: +1 - I'd like to add that you should make this a console app.

Comment: IF the logic is simple you can also create a stored procedure and execute it as a job within sql. But task scheduler would be the best

Comment: @IAbstract: thanks for the answer. The logic is simple: I take two columns from the Source DB by making a query (**quantity** and **customer**), then from the Destination DB I check if the customer exisit and if that is the case I add one row to a existing table with **customerID**, **quantity** and **current month**. Is it feasible with your solution?

Comment: @francesco it _sounds_ like a reasonably straight forward insert..into..select query that does actually involve any logic (except maybe generating some sort of month number column value)

Comment: @andynormancx: so do you suggest me to use an SSIs package with SQL CASE instead of using a console application and the task scheduling?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not really clued up on the details of SSIS, someone else will have to answer that in detail. But yes, if the job really does come down to running a query, there are better ways of doing it than writing your own console app.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new **Scheduled Task**. It would be much easier and you don't have to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a scheduled task that will call your .exe at pre-defined interval.

Go to your control panel and select Scheduled Task and then add scheduled task

Answer (score -1):

You can do it, of course. But I would recommend making it a Windows service.

Comment: Why would you recommend a Windows Service?

Comment: @IAbstract - I would recommend it be a windows service aswell, as this will run in the back ground so the user doesn't have to worry about running the code each month. Set it to run on a time and don't worry about it. Why wouldn't you write it as a service?

Comment: Much, much better to use a scheduled task than to have a dedicated service hanging around just to run a task once a month. And while writing a Windows service is much easier nowadays, running a task via the scheduler is still a lot less hassle.

Comment: @Jethro: "*so the user doesn't have to worry about running the code each month*" ... that's what Scheduled Tasks are for.

Answer (score -2):

If you really want to do it in C# I suggest you write a service, your code is almost Identical to a normal console app.

Check the following link to get started.
[C# Service step by step](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/csharpsvclesson1.aspx)

Comment: A windows service is overkill for something like this.